# Using VLOOKUP to populate another worksheet with rows that happened after today

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet that stores rows of events. I want to populate another worksheet but only with those events that are happening in the future so people can quickly pull up a list of upcoming events.

| Event | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Event #1 | 1 January 2023 |
| Event #2 | 1 September 2023 |

I want it so Worksheet #2 cannot be edited and pulls all of the data from worksheet #1.

I first tried a simple formula to take the data: =IF('Full Schedule'!$B10>=TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE)

This works well enough but if a user INSERTS a row in the middle, it breaks the other worksheet. For example, if worksheet #1 INSERTS a row at 11, the worksheet #2 formulas jump from B10 to B12. I loose the new row.

I tried VLOOKUP, =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1002, Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1002, 2, FALSE), ""). It works well and users can insert a new row but I cannot make it show the rows from today onwards. I also tried INDEX and MATCH but with those I ran into the original problem of inserting a row and loosing that.

Another problem is the first column for the schedule uses event types so there are lots of duplicate. VLOOKUP repeats the first row for the same event types.

I know I can sort for all events that occur after today, but I want to make the process easier as not everyone in the office is comfortable with the sort function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try FILTER formula

Comment: You are writing a lot but saying little. As I understand it, you have problems pulling data from `Sheet1`. If you can put the data in an Excel table you will be able to rewrite any formulas with structured references. Then when you add or remove data, everything gets updated automatically. If you have Microsoft 365, you will be able to do in `Sheet2` whatever is necessary e.g., as mentioned by `user11222393`, use the `FILTER` function with e.g. `=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:F100,B2:B100>TODAY(),"")` or, of course, better with `=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Date]>TODAY(),"")`. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Pivot Table with the data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 and add Slicers. Quick and Easy. Then You can use the Slicers to sort out specific dates or bring up Specific Events.

You might have to format the dates a bit so the selection is easier, there's isn't a way to "search" in a Slicers, but as an option you can but the Dates in Filter to make them searchable.